# How can I change the background color of certain div when clicking on a checkbox with css only?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the innerCircle's `background-color` when clicking a checkbox with css only. How can I access the innerCircle `div`?

```html
<section>

      <label class="button" for="select1">
          <input id="select1" type="checkbox">
          <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>

      <div class="outerCircle">

          <div id='chh' class="innerCircle">

              <div class="sun"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="catBody">

              <div class="leftear"></div>
              <div class="rightear"></div>


              <div class="leftEye"></div>
              <div class="rightEye"></div>


              <div class="noise"></div>

              <div class="neck"></div>



          </div>

      </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: With your current HTML markup this isn't possible with only CSS -- in order for CSS to affect an element based on another element state the element would need to come after the selector and be a sibling -- so with your current markup the only element that you can control from input state is `<span class="slider round"></span>`

Comment: @Simp4Code For now, yes, but in September 2022 Chrome 105 will be out which will support `:has()`. Safari already supports it, leaving only Firefox (but they're working on it...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 2):

move your wanted element after that checkbox and you can get access by css pseudo element like this example

```css
input:checked~.innerCircle {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <label class="button" for="select1">
    <input id="select1" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    <div id="chh" class="innerCircle">
      <div class="sun"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <div class="outerCircle">
    <div class="catBody">
      <div class="leftear"></div>
      <div class="rightear"></div>
      <div class="leftEye"></div>
      <div class="rightEye"></div>
      <div class="noise"></div>
      <div class="neck"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: There are no pseudoelements here. I think you're referring to the `:checked` pseudo**class** instead.

Comment: Yeah! Sorry it was a misstake